# Using a for loop along with multi threading python

Tags: python, multithreading

[I have a parent script that runs 10 child scripts.](http://pastebin.com/jUK36i2B) These scripts are identical apart from the 'name', each script calls a different api, saves to a different folder etc that depends on name.

I originally just copied the script 10 times however I now realise this is ridiculous as if I make one upgrade I have to do it to all 10.

I'm quite new to threading and am not sure if this is allowed, but can I set up a for loop or similar that calls the script and places the 'name' inside:

Ie

```
#parent.py
from threading import Thread
import sys
names =  ['BTC', 'BTS', 'ETH', 'CLAM', 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP' ]

for name in names: 
    sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/'+name)
    import name
    Thread(target=name.main(name)).start()
    Thread(target=name.main(name)).join()
```

Comment: What is the question/issue? Have you tried the code?

Comment: Yes you can, but you shouldn't include the `join` in the loop, as it waits for your thread to finish and will block the start of other threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have list of `threads` , start them in a loop and then wait for them to join in another `for` loop:

```
from threading import Thread
import sys
names =  ['BTC', 'BTS', 'ETH', 'CLAM', 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP' ]
threads = []
for name in names: 
    sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/'+name)
    import name
    T = Thread(target=name.main(name))
    threads.append(T)

for thread_ in threads:
    thread_.start()

for thread_in threads:
    thread_.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you should consider using the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), as `threading` is misleading in Python (in some sense, Python is currently single threaded).

Using this module, it's very easy to do "push the loop" on to the module.

First, define a pool:

```
# start 4 worker processes
pool = Pool(processes=4)
```

Now, if you have a function `f` that runs on a name, you can use

```
pool.map(f, names)
```

This will return only when `f` was applied to each item in `names`, using the `Pool` of 4 processes (in this case). I.e., it's like a "magical" parallel for loop

```
"parallel for" name in names:
    f(name)
```

Comment: This is interesting, thanks for the insight, however i just learnt how to use threading. Don't have the time to en devour down this road for now

Comment: It's basically the same for the `threading` module, though. Just beware that you won't get any real parallelism from it.